# Vectors: Using Pythagoras's theorem for magnitude in the 4th dimension

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, pythagorean-triples

For a simple x and y plane (2 dimensional), to find the distance between two points we would use the formula

$$
a^2 +b^2 = c^2
$$

For a slightly more complicated plane; x,y and z (3 dimensional), to find the distance between two points we would use the formula

$$
d^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2
$$

My question is this; is it possible to use pythagoras's theorem to find the distance/magnitude/modulus between two points in 4 dimensions? And what format would it be in?
Using graphs of triangles and cuboids, I have proved for the 2 dimensional and 3 dimensional pythagorean theorem usage, but since I do not understand the 4th dimension entirely (for convenience and understanding, I assume that it is time), I cannot picture how to start nor work this.

Note: I am a highschool student, and new. If I have not provided enough information or something is unclear please comment and I will try to change it. Thank you in advance

Comment: Fun fact: in special relativity, the corresponding four dimensional spacetime distance is actually $d^2=x^2+y^2+z^2-t^2$.

Comment: @Arthur That is impressive, and I am very greatful! Is there any way to prove that, and/or to find a relationship between the number of dimensions and the corresponding distance within? If you could send a link to direct my research, I'd be immensely thankful. Using your formula all I could find is what seems to be a question paper

Comment: Thank you to @Ethan-Bolker for editing my post to the correct spelling of "Pythagoras"

Comment: Not every problem in Math has a geometric analogue, nor is every problem a physics problem.  N dimensional space doesn't have to be this mind-blowing abstract thing.  You could have multiple dimensions that describe customer behavior in a business application for example.  Yet Euclidean measures distance may still be a relevant metric.

Comment: @DougM I've read some articles and seen some videos about the different dimensions, not to mention used similar mathematics (however not pertinent to this question) so I do not see n-dimensions or the infinite as "mind-blowing". Although I have to say that it is indeed a very impressive concept for our small and discrete existence. If you could kindly expand on the customer behaviour in a business application, I would be grateful as I do not entirely see how that is possible. While I do not do business, I do Economics, and the variables I use are (I think) of limited dimensions. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question.

In the theory of relativity the fourth dimension is time, and the distance formula is weird, as @Arthur comments.

But it's quite possible and (for mathematicians) very natural to study spaces with four (or even $n$) geometric dimensions. You just think of a point as a list of its $n$ coordinates. In the plane points are $(x,y)$. In space they are $(x,y,z)$. In four dimensions they are $(x,y,z,w)$, and the distance $d$ from that point to the origin $(0,0,0,0)$ is, as you might guess, given by the Pythagorean relationship
$$
d^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2 .
$$

As a high school student you might be able to see how to prove that by analogy with how you proved your formula for three dimensions. Later on in your study of mathematics you'll understand how think of it as the *definition* of distance.

The wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-dimensional_space is a good place to begin reading about geometry in the four  dimensions.

Comment: Thank you for the positive feedback and the directions on how to improve my understanding of the topic. I think that with your explanation on the difference of a point (x,y,z,w,n...) from the origin (0,0,0,0,...), I can properly formulate a conjecture, and then I can proceed to find out about @Arthur 's special relativity $$d^2=x^2+y^2+z^2−t^2$$

Answer (score 0):

The Pythagorean theorem works for any dimensions >1. We can find examples by constructing n-tuples made of multiple triples. We begin by find a side $A$ to match the $C$ of any previous triangle.

Here we substitute and solve $C=A=m^2-n^2\implies n=\sqrt{m^2-C}$ where $$\lceil\sqrt{C+1}\space\rceil\le m\le \bigl\lceil\frac{C}{2}\bigr\rceil$$

If any $m$ yields a positive integer $n$, we have $(m,n)$ for a Pythagorean triple.

The simplest triple is $3,4,5$ and we let $A=\sqrt{m^2-5}$ where;
$$m_{min}=\lceil\sqrt{5+1}\space\rceil=3\quad M_{max}=\lceil\frac{5}{2}\space\rceil=3$$
This one was easy: $n=\sqrt{m^2-C}=\sqrt{3^2-5}=2\quad f(3,2)=(5,12,13)$

Now we have $3^2+4^2+12^2=13^2$ and the logic is that, since $5^2=3^2+4^2$, we can substitute $\sqrt{3^2+4^2}$ for the $5$ leg in $5,12,13$.

Let's try $(21,20,29)$. We have $C=29\implies 6\le m \le 15$ and we find $only$ $f(15,14)=(29,420,421)$

If we continue the process begun with $(3,4,5)$ we can find $(3,4,5)\rightarrow(5,12,13)\rightarrow(13,84,85)\rightarrow(85,132,157)\rightarrow(157,12324,12325)\text{ and so on.}$

So far, we have $3^2+4^2+12^2+84^2+132^2+12324^2=12325^2$